# Pyspark filter the dataframe if a row is part of a list's value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a simple Pyspark DF that contains different names

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (43431, "Urban Philosophy"),  
        (53432, "Fix Guru"),
        (63433, "Evergrow")
    ],
    ["id", "name"]
)
```

and I also have a list of names:

```
name_list=['Urban Philosophy Inc.', 'Limited Fix Guru Holdings', 'Contractors Supply Co.', 'Evergrow LLC']
```

I am looping through that list and I would like to filter out the dataframe in case a row of the "name" column is part of the name_list. If it is, I would like to add it to a new dataframe, called filtered. If it is not, it should not be a part of the filtered dataframe. I have written the following code:

```
schema = df.schema
filtered_df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema)
for x in name_list:
    processed_df=df.filter(col('name').isin(x))
    filtered_df = filtered_df.union(processed_df)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work because apparently "isin" works only for exact matches. I can't find any way around, any ideas?

Comment: How long is your `name_list`?

Comment: around 1.000 names

Comment: You can try to build a long regex from the list (the result should be a string), then you can use col("name").rlike(<your regex>). In this way you can get rid of the loop, however with so many names, I have not tried yet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 1000, perhaps this still works but I will leave the alternative idea at bottom.

Your `name_list` has full string so you need to have a condition as `<string in name_list>.contains(col)` or `<string in name_list>.rlike(col)`. Not like `col.contains(<string>)` which is more typical.

PySpark 3.1+ (let me know if you are using lower version)

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

name_list = [F.lit(x) for x in name_list]

df = df.filter(F.aggregate(F.array(name_list),
                           F.lit(False),
                           lambda acc, x: acc | x.contains(F.col('name'))))
```

Alternative idea.

Typically, your want to have search strings to be fuzzier than what you are searching for.

For example, your `name_list` is like `["Urban Philosophy", "Guru", "Evergrow"]`. You can have a rule to omit any common words like `Inc.` or `Ltd.` etc from `name_list`.

If you can clean the `name_list`, your spark code will be simplified as

```
df.filter(F.col('name').rlike('|'.join(name_list)))
```